# Get a file path relative to BUILD file as a string

Tags: bazel

I'm using [pex_pytext](https://github.com/benley/bazel_rules_pex#pex_pytest) and I want to pass some arguments. Some of these args are paths to files: my source code, so that I can get coverage info. There's an `args` parameter that gets passed to the PEX-pytest executable:

```
pex_pytest(
    name = "test",
    srcs = glob(["**/*_test.py"]),
    args = [
        "--cov=path/to/code",
        "--cov-config=path/to/.coveragerc",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":main",
        "//pylibs/test/mock",
    ],
)
```

So here, I'm expecting that I'll get my main code (`:main`) and the `mock` library rolled into the test-pex. Then I want to run it with the `--cov` and `--cov-config` arguments.

The problem is that `args` takes an array of strings, and I don't know how to pass a file-path. I was thinking that if I could ask Bazel to translate a label into a file-path, I could supply the appropriate labels.

How can I get a path relative to my BUILD file and pass it to a rule defined in that BUILD file as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` (for tests) should have ["make" variable substitution](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html), so [`$(location)`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html#predefined_label_variables) may work:

```
"--cov=$(location :path/to/code)"
```

Comment: Ooh, this was so close. But it lets me be pretty confident that the pex_pytest rule would need to be hacked a bit to let me do what I want -- it doesn't pass `deps` along the way I need so the make-style variables can't work. I think this is the correct answer for the general problem, though. Thanks!